# AWS Lambda - What is the best way to encrypt/decrypt text and store in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a node.js Lambda function which stores items in DynamoDB. 
I would like to encrypt one of the item properties before it is stored
in DynamoDB and then decrypt it in another Lambda function that retrieves items.

Is there a simple way to do this using an AWS service or a module that already exists in Lambda?

Or should I upload an external module such as CryptoJS and use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS KMS (Key Management Service) is a service that should be just right for this. You won't need any additional modules because the full AWS SDK is already available in Lambda. And you don't need to worry about having to expose your keys to Lambda.

Comment: Thanks but from what I understand KMS doesn't do any encryption it simply stores the keys you use for encryption

Comment: No, it does perform encryption and decryption with its keys, too. See the AWS KMS Developer Guide section on this at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-encryption.html

Comment: You are correct indeed. I guess I found the intro on it a little ambiguous https://aws.amazon.com/kms/. In any event I should mention that I opted to use the Crypto library anyway because KMS costs $1 per key per month and in my case I needed to generate a unique key for every operation so It would cost too much.

Comment: @Zigglzworth You might want to revisit KMS and your use case.  You'd likely never want a new top level key per operation.  That would be insane.  KMS keys create child keys for each individual use (operation) so that you can have unique keys per item.  Read up on envelope encryption.